# undersanding CakePHP's controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I am going through the CakePHP's beginner tutorial and I have a question:

In the blog tutorial, the have created the following function in the Controller

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
}
```

I'm trying to better understand what this means, specifically

```
$this->Post->find('all')
```

This is a reference to the Controller object's Post object and then calling its find function.
Is this Post object a linkedList (or some other data structure) of Post objects? That seems to be the only way it makes sense but I want to make sure. I am used to OOP in Java and a newbie in OOP in PHP and think I might be missing some pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Model controls the database access.  So, when you want data from your database, in your Controller, you need to use the Model to retrieve it.

```
$this->Post->find('all');
```

tells the 'Post' Model to retrieve all posts.

Best practice is actually to not use the `find()` method from your Controller at all, and instead, call a custom method created in your Model.  For example:

```
//inside PostsController
$posts = $this->Post->getPosts();

//inside Post Model
public function getPosts() {
    return $this->find('all');
}
```

This usually gets a lot more complicated as you add conditions, limits, orders...etc, but done this way, it more closely follows the MVC, the M (Model) is what does all the data-retrieval. (and also makes your code cleaner, so anytime you want to update the find, you only have to do it in one place, and not across many controllers)

Comment: `Best practice is actually to not use the find() method from your Controller at all` this is not accurate. Best practice is to wrap none-trivial logic/calls adhering to "fat models, thin controllers" - `find('all')` does not fit this, wrapping this call does nothing but add abstraction, and remove functionality (by removing the possibility to pass paramters to the find call).

Comment: @AD7six - I disagree, but I think it's beside the point - rarely in an app do you ever literally just use 'findAll()'.  And even if for now, you think you need just a `find('all')`, put it in the model anyway IMO, and you'll be thankful - later, when you decide you need an `'active'=>1` condition (or something of the like), you'll wish your finds were all in a single location.  More flexible, easily-updatable code is more important than worrying about this adding a layer of abstraction.

Comment: @AD7six - I don't, but I have a guess now that you mention that :)  We'll have to agree to disagree.  Feel free to put 20+ find('all')`s throughout your Controllers.  I'll have mine all call a Model's method.  When time comes where you need to add additional parameters, have fun going through them all.  Granted, as I pointed out above, your reasoning for this being "not accurate" is assuming anyone actually uses a straight-up `find('all')`, which I see very rarely.

Comment: Bottom line IMO, it's still great advice for a beginning/intermediate Cake developer to put  all find()s in the model.  When they become more experienced and learn how/when they might not need to do that, then more power to them. :)

Answer (score 0):

It call a method `find` of your model Post.
your model have find because it extend a AppModel.

```
   App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
  class Post extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'Post';
    }
```

and return ll be something like this

(its only example, it ll depend ur database and ur model post/user... etc)

```
Array
(
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [desc] => 'it is a test post'
            [user_id] => 2

        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => 'rafael'
            [phone] => '9999-000'
        )
)
```

and this array ll be disponible for your views acess in variable 'posts'.

Comment: What I meant in my question was - does the Post class (from its extension from AppModel) actually get  function to find ALL posts? Is it correct from a OOP perspective to give a class a function to find all instances of its type? It would seem that a 'find' function shouldn't go inside the Post class but rather the Controller should create an array of Posts create a find function in the controller.

Comment: @user1015214 the `'all'` parameter, is just a way to retrieve your data. There are several ways to fetch them, such as `'list'`, `'threaded'`, `'first'`. The `find()` method, takes also as second argument an array which can contain a number of conditions. Those are interpreted as `SQL` clauses. So you only fetch your data according to your conditions. `'all'` means the way the retrieved data, are organized